# Processing additional information form fields in PHP/CodeIgniter form and storing in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

I'm working on a form for a home building company - users can specify the options that they'd like in their home. I store the general information from the form (formID, name, address, phone, etc.) in a table called 'designForm'.

I have another table called 'designOptions' that holds every option that is available for the homes (optionID, optionLocation, optionName, optionDescription).

There is also a table called 'FormOptions' that will hold a record for each option that is selected on the form (formID, optionID)

On the form, each option is represented by a checkbox with it's value set to the optionID. Some of the option checkboxes show additional input or select fields when they're checked. The additional info will **not** always be the same. Sometimes it's Ceiling Height, other times it could be Shower Size or something else. Below are some examples.

```
<span class="additional-info-wrap">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="38">Whirlpool Tub
  </label>
  <div class="additional-info hide">
    <select class="form-control" name="masterBathWhirlpoolSize">
      <option value="None Specified">None Specified</option>
      <option value="3'x5'">3'x5'</option>
      <option value="3'x6'">3'x6'</option>
      <option value="4'x6'">4'x6'</option>
      <option value="5'x5' Corner Unit">5'x5' Corner Unit</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</span>
<span class="additional-info-wrap">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="39">Shower / Tub
  </label>
  <div class="additional-info hide">
    <select class="form-control" name="masterBathTubSize">
      <option value="None Specified">None Specified</option>
      <option value="3'x5'">3'x5'</option>
      <option value="3'x6'">3'x6'</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</span>
<span class="additional-info-wrap">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="46">Dining Room
  </label>
  <div class="additional-info hide">
    <input type="number" name="roomsDiningHeight" placeholder="Ceiling Height" class="form-control" disabled="">
  </div>
</span>
<span class="additional-info-wrap">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="47">Family Room / Great Room
  </label>
  <div class="additional-info hide">
    <input type="number" name="roomsFamilyHeight" placeholder="Ceiling Height" class="form-control" disabled="">
  </div>
</span>
```

Using CodeIgniter, I insert the basic form data into the 'designForm' field, grab the formID and then process the options array with the following:

```
            $options = $this->input->post('options');

            foreach ($options as $option ){
                $option_data = array(
                  'optionID' =>($option),
                  'formID' =>($form_id)
                );
            }
```

**My question is**: what is the best way to process that additional information which is exposed when a user checks the checkbox? I'm asking for the best way to name the fields in the HTML (multi-dimensional array?), process the fields in PHP/CodeIgniter and then store them in the MySQL DB.

I'd like to be able to store the additional info field's name and value in the 'FormOptions' table, but I'm not sure if that makes sense, or how I would go about doing it. The information in those fields really applies to the specific option, so I don't believe it makes sense to store them in the 'designForm' table.

Answer (score 0):

i solved a problem near this like your problem this way:

My form was N fields... and i never know what of they i need to send...

I made my options and checkboxes as multidimensional array.

And later i get the data from form using:

```
$formData = $this->input->post();
```

The result will be and array with all POSTED data from the form. Then you can manage in a controller or object the way you need to send, to database, or for email.